# MySQL complex LEFT JOIN to simulate UNION like query

Tags: php, mysql

I have 4 MySQL tables, `sh_comenzi`, `sh_comenzi_prods`, `sh_delivery`, `sh_delivery_items`.

The table data looks something like this:

`sh_comenzi` table:

```
id  pid doc_date    status  deleted date_added  date_modified
1   12  1427534088  0       0       1427534088  1427534088
2   14  1427534088  1       0       1427534088  1427534088
3   17  1427534088  0       0       1427534088  1427534088
4   1   1427534088  0       0       1427534088  1427534088
5   2   1427534088  1       0       1427534088  1427534088
```

`sh_comenzi_prods` table:

```
id  idc pOrder  cPos    fid idp quantity    delivery_date
1   2   aaa     1       1   2   100         1427534088
2   2   aaa     2       1   89  100         1427534088
3   5   qqq     1       2   10  100         1427534088
4   5   qqq     2       2   11  100         1427534088
5   5   qqq     3       2   10  100         1427534088
6   5   qqq     4       2   14  100         1427534088
7   4   1234q   1       1   135 100         1427534088
8   5   123a    1       2   2   100         1427534088
```

`sh_delivery` table structure

```
id  status  date_added
1   0       1427534088
2   1       1427534088
3   0       1427534088
4   1       1427534088
```

`sh_delivery_items` table:

```
id  delivery_id idc cPos
1   1           1   1
2   2           1   1
3   4           5   1
4   4           5   2
5   4           5   4
```

I want to have a MySQL query that shows me for a selected `sh_comenzi` id (let's say `sh_comenzi.id = 5`) all records from `sh_comenzi_prods` that do not exist in `sh_delivery_items` with the condition `sh_comenzi_prods.idc = sh_delivery_items.idc` and `sh_comenzi.status = 1` and `sh_delivery.status = 0`. Now, for the hard part, to those results I want to be able to add all records from `sh_delivery_items` with the `delivery_id = 4` and `sh_delivery_items.idc = 5`

The tables are related one to each other by this criteria:
- `sh_comenzi.id = sh_comenzi_prods.idc` 
- `sh_delivery.id = sh_delivery_items.delivery_id`
- `sh_comenzi_prods.idc = sh_delivery_items.idc`

Could someone give me one ideea of query without UNION that would give the next result?

```
delivery_id idc cPos
4           5   1
4           5   2
4           5   4
NULL        5   3
NULL        2   2
```

The query used by me:

```
SELECT sh_delivery_items.delivery_id, sh_comenzi_prods.idc, sh_comenzi_prods.cPos
        FROM   sh_comenzi_prods
        LEFT JOIN sh_comenzi ON sh_comenzi.id = sh_comenzi_prods.idc
        LEFT JOIN sh_delivery_items ON (sh_delivery_items.idc = sh_comenzi_prods.idc AND sh_delivery_items.cPos = sh_comenzi_prods.cPos)
        LEFT JOIN sh_delivery ON sh_delivery.id = sh_delivery_items.delivery_id
        WHERE sh_comenzi.status=1 AND idc=5 AND (delivery_id=4 OR (sh_delivery_items.id IS NULL OR sh_delivery.status=0))
        ORDER BY sh_comenzi_prods.cPosasc
```

Here is the sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c775e/2

Comment: Can you please use Clear naming conventions for tables? sh_comenzi,sh_comenzi_prods does not make any sense and confusing  and complicated too.

Comment: sh_comenzi is the orders header and sh_comenzi_prods is the line level table structure. I would have put the sqlfiddle but for some reason it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements are a bit hard to follow -- which is why sample data and desired results always help a question.

However, your query has a possible logical flow, which is the use of `where` with `left join`.  Conditions in the `where` would normally only go on the first table in a series of `left join` conditions.  So, the following may do what you want:

```
    SELECT sh_delivery_items.delivery_id, sh_comenzi_prods.idc, sh_comenzi_prods.cPos
    FROM sh_comenzi_prods LEFT JOIN
         sh_comenzi
         ON sh_comenzi.id = sh_comenzi_prods.idc AND
            sh_comenzi.status = 1 LEFT JOIN
         sh_delivery_items
         ON sh_delivery_items.idc = sh_comenzi_prods.idc AND 
            sh_delivery_items.cPos = sh_comenzi_prods.cPos LEFT JOIN
         sh_delivery
         ON sh_delivery.id = sh_delivery_items.delivery_id AND
            (delivery_id = 4 OR sh_delivery.status = 0)
    WHERE sh_comenzi_prods.idc = 5
    ORDER BY sh_comenzi_prods.cPosasc
```

Comment: I couldn't handle a sqlfiddle example and that's why I had to choose the hard and long explain..